# How to reverse return value?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [];


var a1;
arr.push( ( (a1 = [1, 2, 'random']).num = 5 ) && a1 )
```

Is there a way to not have to define the variable `a1` and push the array `a1` after setting the `num` property on it.

If I were to take out `&& a1` the number `5` would be pushed to `arr`. So anyways to push the array without having to define `a1`?

Comment: Its kind of hard to understand what you are trying to achive....

Comment: run it in the console. The code is correct, yet I want to know if anyone knows how to do the same as above without defining `a1`

Comment: why are you trying to do "&& a1"?

Comment: @gabriel `&& a1` allows me to return `a1` and push it to `arr`

Comment: I would go with what @Dan D. recommended, readability is extremely important when writing code

Comment: I'm use to writing code like this it's readable to me. I'm not doing it a lot it's just once in my particular script. So it's fine.

This is how I learned to do that a while back:http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510

But I was trying to shorten the above code

Comment: The && operator will return the second value if the first is true, otherwise it will return the first value. You are comparing a valid object with itself, so technically, it should always return the second value, which is a1.

Comment: @Frank I understand my code. I was wondering if it can get even shorter than it is. (sorry if this comment wasn't for me)

Comment: I was just throwing that out there because it is sort of obscure. You could just push an object literal... But if you need the variable handy as well, this is not a good option.

Comment: No not with an array if you were passing an object you could but you can't define an array, specify a property on it and return it in one line without a helper function

Comment: @gabriel Yes you can with an array the above code does that.

Comment: I forgot to add one more condition to that, you can't do that without specifying a variable name

instead of attaching a property to an array why not send it as an object

arr.push({arr: [1, 2, 'random'], num: 5});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can shorten this code is by leaving off the variable declaration of a1 entirely:

```
var arr = [];
//var a1;
arr.push( ( (a1 = [1, 2, 'random']).num = 5 ) && a1 );
```

This actually works, but I think it's probably better to leave your variable definition.

You could do this:

```
var a1=( (a1 = [1, 2, 'random']).num = 5 ) && a1;
arr.push(a1);
```

At least now you don't have an empty variable declaration.

I ran a test on my second solution to see if a1 was in fact being defined globally before being stored in the local variable a1:

```
    var array=[];
    function scopeTest(){
        biff=10;// Global
        var a1 = (( a1 = [1, 2, 'random']).num = 5 ) && a1;// Private?
        array.push(a1);
    }
    scopeTest();

    alert("array: "+array);// 1,2,random
    alert("array[0].num: "+array[0].num);// 5
    alert("biff: "+biff);// 10
    alert("a1: "+a1);//a1 is undefined and therefore not global.
```

Defining a1 this way is totally fine!

Comment: Yea but leaves a memory leak. Taking off the `var` makes `a1` global

Comment: Is that true for my second solution as well? Because it looks like it would have to define a1 globally and then store it in the local variable a1... So it probably is. I think you may already have it as short as it can go without making the code less efficient.

Comment: I like this one efficiency wise because I'm also not overwriting `a1` as well. didn't think of this thanks

Comment: Thanks didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a helper function?

```
function set(obj, name, value) {
    obj[name] = value;
    return obj;
}

var arr = [];
arr.push( set([1, 2, 'random'], 'num', 5) );
```

For one instance even:

```
var arr = [];

var a1 = [1, 2, 'random'];
a1.num = 5;
arr.push(a1);
```

Would be more readable.

Comment: NO that's worst. It's only for one instance.